# How to publish posts on the home page?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some code:

***models.py** (model Posts)*:

```
STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)
 

 class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True db_index=True )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)   
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
class PostList(generic.ListView):

    queryset= Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-publish')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6
```

**urls.py**

```
 path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
```

After I create an article in the admin panel, I click publish, the article is not displayed on the main page. But if you restart the server (manage.py run server), then the article appears on the main page.

**Question:**
How to make the article appear on page reload and does not require server reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that with such a construction:

**views.py**

> ```
> class PostList(generic.ListView):
>   queryset= Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-publish')
>   template_name = 'index.html'
>   paginate_by = 6
> ```

we read posts from the database only at the moment of server restart.

I created just such a function and it helped to solve the problem

```
def postlist(request):
  queryset= Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-publish')
  return render (request, index.html, {'queryset': queryset})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for a website I had a while back. What I had found is that the cache was not refreshing often enough (since the update/changed page was not cached in my browser, it was like it was invisible to it). The solution for this was (on the server end) to update the .htaccess file. 'Cache-control' is the key function. In my case, the code looked like this:

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|html)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1200, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

Here is more information:
https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/cache-control/

Comment: thanks, but I have a development server on my local machine

Comment: and earlier articles were published immediately after I created them in the admin panel

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear to me and I do not have experience running a server locally. Good luck.